# Oracle Function for the string stringtokenizer

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, split

I am new to Oracle PL/SQL. I have requirement to create function to tokenized the below string

```
test|1$test2|4$test4|5$test9|3
```

into below rows

```
Key   value 
test    1
test2   4
test4   5
test9   3
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: hint: split the records via `regex_substr(..)` and then insert and as you want a function set the return type as `Record` as its a mixture of rows and columns

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a (PL/SQL) function, SQL can do that:

```
SQL> with
  2  -- input string
  3  test (col) as
  4    (select 'test|1$test2|4$test4|5$test9|3' from dual),
  5  -- intermediate CTE which creates rows
  6  inter as
  7    (select regexp_substr(col, '[^$]+', 1, level) val
  8     from test
  9     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '\$') + 1
 10    )
 11  -- create two columns out of each substring
 12  select substr(val, 1, instr(val, '|') - 1) key,
 13         substr(val, instr(val, '|') + 1) value
 14  from inter;

KEY        VALUE
---------- ----------
test       1
test2      4
test4      5
test9      3

SQL>
```

But, if it *has to be* a function, it shouldn't be too difficult to convert the above code into one.